# How to fix "Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"?

Tags: typescript

```
interface IData {
    title: string;
    slug: string;
    published_at: string;
    isPopular: boolean;
}

const product: IData = {
    title: "Title 1",
    slug: "title-1",
    published_at: "2012",
    isPopular: true,
};

function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>) {
    const items = <IData>{};
    // // Ensure only the minimal needed data is exposed
    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (field === "isPopular") {
            items[field] = product.isPopular;
        }
        if (typeof product[field] !== "undefined") {
            items[field] = product[field]; // I am getting error here items[field]
        }
    });
    return items;
}
```

I am getting the error at "items[field]". I already tried a few solutions to other similar questions. But nothing worked for me. What I am missing here?
Error message: Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: `{}` is not a valid `IData`. `IData` has 4 mandatory properties and `{}` is missing them.

Comment: Then, how could I define an empty object?

Comment: You could make properties optional, use initial values in `{}` or don't use the interface.

Comment: I gave initial value but it still has same problem

Comment: Can you update the question and show your changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two distinct issues:

1. Your `items` is not a valid `IData` object. It doesn't have all of the required `IData` properties.
2. In your loop, TypeScript doesn't know the specific type of `field` (just that it's one of `keyof IData`) and so doesn't know whether `items[field]` is `string` or `boolean`; as a result, you can't assign to it. Even though **you** know that `items[field]` and `product[field]` will have the same type, TypeScript doesn't.

The first issue is simple: Define it as a partial `IData`:

```typescript
const items: Partial<IData> = {};
```

You have at least three options for fixing #2:

- Make the function fully typesafe with a helper.

  ```
  function copyProp<ObjType extends object, KeyType extends keyof ObjType>(obj: ObjType, key: KeyType, value: ObjType[KeyType]) {
      obj[key] = value;
  }
  function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>) {
      const items: Partial<IData> = {};
      for (const field of fields) {
          copyProp(items, field, product[field]);
      }
      return items;
  }
  ```

  That works because `copyProp` ensures that the value passed in (`product[field]`) is type-compatible with the target object's field via `ObjType[KeyType]`.

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#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)
- Tell TypeScript to ignore the error. This is **rarely** the right thing to do, but sometimes in cases where you **know** the error isn't important, it's not unreasonable.

  ```
  function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>) {
      const items: Partial<IData> = {};
      for (const field of fields) {
          // @ts-ignore
          items[field] = product[field];
      }
      return items;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gKGSOTGDABsIAuZAZzClAHMBuQ428gVyZvsZCt2RAA5cARuWC0AFhAAmAfSx8GzNsWTSACgHsx5OFBrjduynBBsAvvnwJdIeshFRd8rgjA0MWHAF48YRIyShoAIgAVUJQARnCAGmDOHgjSCggAWnikzTFJaTklFWRwgCYABliyxOCdfS5DYxIoLggk6zZ8GC4QL2BHZCYIMABhXS4oWggAIQBPAGVuJgAKGGAIcnlaGgBBKCg4OYAeAGsIOd0YNExsAD4ASiDNBycwLUgAWx3kbSNSODkY6+e7IQK4TrBGC6KDIFavZzrTbyZBXZBIra0J4ETSaAD0eOQAAEwLRMsAmCAYRBgpoyBBvgBtDHyAC6YJcbg8XmZGy2rI0xFsmigI0mIA+DNoNiAA)
- You could do an end-run around it by hiding the issue behind `Object.fromEntries`:

  ```typescript
  function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>) {
      const items: Partial<IData> = Object.fromEntries(fields.map(field => [field, product[field]]));
      return items;
  }
  ```

  [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3gKGSOTGDABsIAuZAZzClAHMBuQ428gVyZvsZCt2RAA5cARuWC0AFhAAmAfSx8GzNsWTSACgHsx5OFBrjduynBBsAvvnwJdIeshFRd8rgjA0MWHAF48YRIyShoAIgAVUJQARnCAGmDOHgjSCggAWnikzTFJaTklFWRwgCYABliyxOCdfS5DYxIoLggk6zZ8GC4QL2BHZCYIMABhXS4oWggAIQBPAGVuJgAKGGAIcnlaGgBBKCg4OYAeAGsIOd0YNExsAD4ASiDNBycwLUgAWx3kbSNSODkY6+e7IQIAeXEACsIF4AHQwNyfACi4EYEFoaw2W1ocM+cBEWM28jBd2QAG11sSEi43B4vJTsfIALrMh4PDTEKAjSYgD4Qb42IA)

The first of those is fully typesafe (I think). The second two are both imperfect, but in a **very** contained way. `getCourseBySlug` is a small function and within it you know that `items[field]` and `product[field]` have the same type.

Note that in all of those, I removed your `typeof product[field] !== "undefined"` test. There's no reason for it, the type of `fields` ensures that `field` is a valid key for `product`, and none of `IData`'s properties is optional.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because items is an empty object so items[field] will "never" exist

switching to a reduce method will both solve the error (since you are not trying to access a value that doesn't exist) and cleans up your function slightly

```
function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>): IData {
    return fields.reduce((acc: IData, field: keyof IData) => {
        if (typeof product[field] !== "undefined") {
            return { ...acc, [field]: product[field] };
        } else {
            return acc;
        }
    }, {
        title: "",
        slug: "",
        published_at: "",
        isPopular: false,
    });
}
```

--edit--

if you want your returned object to be a subset of the original as pointed out in comments then you can replace the return and accumulator types with Partial

```
function getCourseBySlug(fields: Array<keyof IData>): Partial<IData> {
    return fields.reduce((acc: Partial<IData>, field: keyof IData) => {
        if (typeof product[field] !== "undefined") {
            return { ...acc, [field]: product[field] };
        }
    }, {});
}
```